# MVC3 C# Potentially dangerous request error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

I have an MVC3 C#. Web App.  One of our properties uses an RTF control for our TextBoxFor controls:

```
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SowDescription,
                    (object)new
                    {
                        rows = 7,
                        cols = 65,
                        @class = "celltext2 save-alert attachmentEditor",
                        disabled = "disabled"
                    }
```

THe attachmentEditor class uses CkEditor.  So there are html tags embedded in the control for Bold, Italics, etc.  A user pasted some data into this TextArea and we received this error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (SowDescription="<br />  <br />  <u><..."). ********
```

We use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in other cases, but the using it in the Html.TextAreFor() helper we get this error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Any ideas how we can Encode/Decode the using the Html.TextAreaFor() helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try decorating the `SowDescription` viewmodel property with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

Comment: @Pablo...when I use [AllowHtml] my app doesn't recognize it.  Am I missing a reference?

Comment: @MikeTWebb Can you check if you are referencing System.Web.Mvc?

Comment: @dpwilson...I was referenve the MVC2 version of System.Web.Mvc.  I changed to MVC3 and it works.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In  your model,before SowDescription definition add  this

```
 [AllowHtml]
```

You need  System.Web.Mvc reference for using it

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:
UI:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('Description', { toolbar: '1', htmlEncodeOutput: true});
```

Controller:

```
model.Body = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Body);
```