# Need some advise on what to do with this task

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

rather than this being an actual question I need some help with my assignment I'm working on.

Basically I was assigned to do a website that has two sides to it's login

- Admin
- Guest

When an Admin is logged in he is able to Create a "System", delete the System and Edit it.

A system will basically be something for example "Word 2014" and in the System the admin will be able to add tabs to it with divs which will be filled with a User Manual to how to use that Program.

So in simple Terms what I'm working on is an ONLINE User Manual, but instead of having one website for one system Manual, I need to have 1 website with loads of Manuals for different Systems.

The guest will be able to login and Access the Current Systems with their respective Manuals and through a CK Editor they can edit the Text, add to it, etc.

Any ideas to what I can work on?

So far I've done the following

1. Registering to the website
2. Log-in / Log-out functionality
3. Create System / Delete

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What framework have you started with? WebForms, MVC, WebPages? Have you already established a database connection for your "System" CRUD? Is this an academic assignment? If so, do you need to show an awareness of scaling, security, etc? Your question is a bit broad as it stands.

Comment: Hey Daz, yes, it's an academic project.

Comment: @Daz Basically I've done the connection to my database and I'm also using WebForms for this case

Comment: This question is far too broad, you need a programming partner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you're using WebForms for your acedemic project then you aren't required to show how you would create a web application from first principals, because you're using the WebForms framework to provide some abstraction on top of basic HTML.

Some would argue WebForms is a bit old-hat and atypical of modern web application frameworks, and MVC might be a more appropriate framework for learning something that's a bit closer to HTML. If the choice of framework is yours, you need to consider if you've chosen the right one.

If you want to stay with WebForms and you don't want to reinvent the wheel, consider using scaffolding to create your basic CRUD forms: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6c3614f-83be-4749-afbc-8da394b6ea86

Using scaffolding will encourage good practice, such as using data models to split your presentation layer from your data layers. It will structure your project and encourage you to concentrate on the logic of your application rather than the basic mechanics (IMHO).

Once you have scaffolded your basic CRUD pages you can modify them to include things like CK Editor (there's a WebForms nuget package for CK Editor).

Bear in mind the security considerations of putting a HTML editor in the hands of your users. You will need to ensure they can't inject malicious javascript code into their system manuals. For me, this is a more useful learning area than simply putting the forms together, as there are umpteen frameworks you could use for the 'grunt work'.

Putting a HTML editor on your forms won't work until you relax the ASP.Net security rules: [MVC3 C# Potentially dangerous request error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489853/mvc3-c-sharp-potentially-dangerous-request-error) (something you could discuss the merits of in your write-up).

Comment: The only fact I'm worried is how to make the System - > add a new System and adding tabs to the system specifically....